# Как интерпретировать код PERL на PHP?

Tags: php, perl

Привет всем! Правильно ли я перевел perl на php?
PERL

```
my @indexes;
        for my $i ( 0 .. $L - 1 ) {
            my %seen;
            while (1) {
                my $rand = int( rand( $self->d * $SCALE ) );
                if ( !$seen{$rand} ) {
                    $seen{$rand} = 1;
                    last if keys %seen == $self->k * $SCALE; // ??????
                }
            }
            push( @indexes, [ sort { $a <=> $b } keys %seen ] );
        }
        $self->_indexes( \@indexes );
```

PHP

```
$indexes = null;
    for($q=0; $q<$L; $q++){
      $seen = null;
      while(true){
        $rand = rand(0, $d*$SCALE);
        if(!$seen[$rand]){
          $seen[$rand] = 1;
          if(count($seen) == $k * $SCALE)
            break;
        }
      }
      $indexes[] = asort($seen);
    }
```

Comment: А запустить оба куска кода на одних и тех же данный и отловить очевидные проблемы вы не пробовали? Почему?

Answer (score 1):

Почти все верно кроме того что в `perl` в `@indexes` складываются ссылки на массив, а в `php true` (т.к. `asort` возвращает `bool`, а не массив)

Также стоит учитывать что

- в perl использовались св-ва инстанса (`$self->*`), а в php простые переменные;
- если цикл не выполнится в `perl` в `indexes` останется пустой массив, а в `php null`.